# What's the basic operation of a brute force median algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm that goes something like this

> $$\begin{align}
> &\mathbf{ALGORITHM}\operatorname{BruteForceMedian}(A[0..n-1])\\
> &\mbox{// Returns the median value in a given array $A$ of $n$ numbers. This is}\\
> &\mbox{// the $k$th element, where $k=|n/2|$, if the array was sorted.}\\
> &k\leftarrow|n/2|\\
> &\mathbf{for}\ i\ \mathbf{in}\ 0\ \mathbf{to}\ n-1\ \mathbf{do}\\
> &\quad\text{numsmaller}\leftarrow0\quad\hbox{// How many elements are smaller than $A[i]$}\\
> &\quad\text{numeral}\leftarrow0\qquad\hbox{// How many elements are equal to $A[i]$}\\
> &\quad\mathbf{for}\ j\ \mathbf{in}\ 0\ \mathbf{to}\ n-1\ \mathbf{do}\\
> &\qquad\mathbf{if}\ A[j]<A[i]\ \mathbf{then}\\
> &\qquad\quad\text{numsmaller}\leftarrow\text{numsmaller}+1\\
> &\qquad\mathbf{else}\\
> &\qquad\quad\mathbf{if}\ A[j]=A[i]\ \mathbf{then}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\text{numequal}\leftarrow\text{numequal}+1\\
> &\quad\mathbf{if}\ \text{numsmaller}<k\ \mathbf{and}\ k\le(\text{numsmaller}+\text{numequal})\ \mathbf {then}\\
> &\qquad\mathbf{return}\ A[i]
> \end{align}$$

I figure as this is a nested loop algorithm its efficiency class would be $O(n^2)$. I am just confused as to what the algorithm's "Basic Operation" should be. Is it the comparison operator down the bottom that (when correct) returns the median value of the array?

Comment: You can also improve the title.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "basic operation". In what sense would an instruction be "basic"? Usually, by "basic operations" one refers to the fundamental instructions allowed by your computational model, but in analysis of algorithms we are generally operating at an higher level of abstraction.

Comment: Please check the Markdown help: SE has code formatting; using LaTeX for pseudo code is probably a bad idea.